# Run out of process background task as administrator

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, background-task, etw

I'm currently working on a UWP app that has an out-of-process background task (in a windows runtime component project). In the background task I'm trying to run a trace event session from the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session` library, but it requires administrator privileges to run. Is there any way I can run the background task process as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

hi maybe this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0fdf5fe0-f35e-49d4-a635-8353257d31a1/uwpcis-uwp-app-allowed-to-request-administrator-privilege-when-launching-the-uwp-app?forum=wpdevelop) will help you.

> Hi,
> No, auto-elevation for apps is not supported for Desktop Bridge apps.
> This policy is called out in the preparation guide for the Desktop Bridge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare(bullet #2)
> But you could tell users to run your app as admin.
> The user can choose to run your app as admin by right click your app and choose more and you could find the option as Run as Administartor

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Currently, UWP apps don't have the option to Run as administrator.

Another thing that needs to say is that with the 1809 update for Windows 10, **desktop bridge apps** can now declare a new capability -`allowElevation` in order to require elevation.